# Slider with multiple navigational options loses index(s) and either breaks or falls out of place?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have been building a product tour and thanks to a member's help on here earlier, I was able to include a "navigation" into my existing tour. The problem is that there are 3 different ways to navigate..

- side arrows on the screen
- arrow keys (left and right)
- slider timeline on bottom of the screen

I noticed that after scrolling through my **[working project](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3772987986&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=667248&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP#connect)** wiht a variety of nav options, the slider will break. You can try by sliding with arrow keys, then using the bottom nav, just general use breaks the slider.

It seems like my index is falling out of place, when I was implementing the slider a user suggested to use this:
I am also catching an

> uncaught reference error: 'e' is not defined

But since I didn't write the code, I'm not sure how to fix it..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var current = 0,
    $panels = $('.tour-panel'),
    noOfPanels = $panels.size() - 1,
    $currentElement = $panels.eq(current),
    $nextElement = $currentElement,
    $links = $('.slideshow-timeline a');

    function anyElement( slidePosition ) {
    $nextElement = $panels.eq(next);
    if (slidePosition > current) {
        $currentElement.removeClass('active-tour');
        $currentElement.addClass('fadeOutLeft');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $nextElement.addClass('active-tour fadeInRight');
        }, 50);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $currentElement.removeClass('fadeOutLeft');
        }, 750);
    } else if (slidePosition < current) {
        $currentElement.removeClass('active-tour');
        $currentElement.addClass('fadeOutRight');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $nextElement.addClass('active-tour fadeInLeft');
        }, 50);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $currentElement.removeClass('fadeOutRight');
        }, 750);
    } else {
        // in this case the element selected and the one showing are the same
        // there are no class changes to be applied
    }
    current = slidePosition;
    $currentElement = $nextElement;
}

$('.previous').click(function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        previous = noOfPanels;
    } else {
        previous = current - 1;
    }
    anyElement( previous );
});
Mousetrap.bind('left', function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        previous = noOfPanels;
    } else {
        previous = current - 1;
    }
    anyElement( previous );
});

$('.next').click(function () {
    if (current === noOfPanels) {
        next = 0;
    } else {
        next = current + 1;
    }
    anyElement( next );
});
Mousetrap.bind('right', function () {
    if (current === noOfPanels) {
        next = 0;
    } else {
        next = current + 1;
    }
    anyElement( next );
});

    $links.on('click', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    var next = $links.index(this);
    anyElement( next );
    });

});
```

It seems like it's having trouble deciphering between the two when it comes to navigating the slider, I used this HTML to build the lower navigation as well. It's built with the idea of linking to an `#id` and then using my slider to reference the id and pull that to screen.

```
<ul class="slideshow-timeline">
    <li class="active-target-main"><a href="#target" class="js-goto-panel">Target</a>
        <ul class="current-section">
            <li><a href="#target-1">Tracking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-2">Segmentation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-3">Wealth Screening</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-4">Targeting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#target-5">Cultivation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#connect">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#convert">Convert</a></li>
    <li><a href="#optimize">Optimize</a></li>
</ul>
```

What would be my solution to fixing the order of the indexes, as if it breaks, it completely destroys the User Experience. All of your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your script breaks as soon as it executes. That is not good.
The problematic code here is this line (around line 164):

```
$(".sticky").offset().top;
```

When it executes there seems to be no element with the class `sticky`.

Also try changing the following code (around line 66):

```
h.on("click", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = h.index(this);
    b(i)
})
```

to

```
h.on("click", function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = h.index(this);
    b(i)
})
```

There seem to be several problems in your script so the best approach would be to check the console and debug the critical errors.

For example: You have added the argument to the above mentioned function. Now your script is able to execute further and we get an error we didn't see before (because the script is only now able to get there).

The new error is that the `h` is not defined. Please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish. Could you also create a JSFiddle? (Editing it would be easier if you did.)

Comment: Oh hello Ivan, yes I did, that is this code right now. The e is getting thrown on the "links section".

My problem is that the indexes don't sync and you'll be for example: index3 with the buttons, but on index 5 with the nav links. 

The first problem is because that code is for a different page, I will have to separate the JS file.

Comment: Now around line 66 you have a **ReferenceError**, meaning you didn't define `h`.

Comment: That's with the code to told me to swap out, where do I define `h`?

Comment: You're probably using an **uglifier**. For debugging it would be helpful if you didn't during development :)

Comment: I am on a framework that does the minify automatically, I can't change that. I am coding in pretty-print though.

Comment: Can you tell me the framework? Can you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101415/discussion-between-ether-and-ivan-modric).